# Python/Linux-How to create a script that monitor USB ports and print the mount point path when a new USB Storage Device is plugged?

Tags: python, linux, usb

My goal is to run a script on infinite loop(only being stopped by keyboard interrupt) that when a I plug a device, the code prints "New drive mounted at /mount/point/here" on the screen. I tried to use pyudev but I couldn't get it to work. Can anyone show me how to do this? I'm still new on interacting with Linux events.

Comment: pyudev sounds like the lib to go, if you want to interface with python. Udev itself also has this capability (udevadm monitor)

Answer (score 0):

For the device monitoring use something like the code below inside a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pyudev

context = pyudev.Context()

path = pyudev.Devices.from_sys_path

monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by('block')

# enumerate at device connection
for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
  if 'ID_FS_TYPE' in device:
    if device.action == 'add':
        if device.device_node[5:7] == 'sd':
          print('New drive mounted at /', device.device_node)
```